# Button with v-on:click that switches between the classes btn-primary and btn-primary-outline not working

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4

Im working on a button that opens a modal. By default it should have the btn-primary-outline class (Blue text, transparent background, blue border), when clicked it should have the btn-primary class (White text, blue background, blue border). But its not working, the button stays trasparent, the text blue, and all its doing is toggling the blue button border on and off.

**HTML:**

```
<button v-on:click="settingsButtonIsActive = !settingsButtonIsActive" 
    class="btn margin-top-half center-block col-xs-12"
    :class="[settingsButtonIsActive ? 'btn-primary' : '', 'btn-primary-outline']">
<strong>{{labels.lblButtonConfiguration}}</strong>
</button>
```

**Controller:**

```
data = {
     settingsButtonIsActive: false
}
```

I feel like the button doesnt like not having any of those 2 clases defined, but i cant think of any other way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "mistake" you use an array syntax but the logic of "else" is empty `''` (If `settingsButtonIsActive` is false render => `''`) + always render `btn-primary-outline` ([The (ternary) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) inside `0` index - `btn-primary-outline` on `1` index).

For example this:

```
:class="[settingsButtonIsActive ? 'btn-primary' : '', 'btn-primary-outline', 'hello', 'world']">
```

render:

```
<button class="btn-primary btn-primary-outline hello world">
```

Not in "vue" this is your logic:

```
var element = document.getElementById("myDIV");

if(settingsButtonIsActive){
  element.classList.add("btn-primary");
}
else{
  element.classList.add(""); 
}

element.classList.add("btn-primary-outline");
```

This is the correct markup (For -or- a -or- b) - shortcut for "if else":

```
class="settingsButtonIsActive ? 'btn-primary' : 'btn-primary-outline'">
```

**No need her for array syntax:** https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Array-Syntax

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    msg: "settingsButtonIsActive",
    settingsButtonIsActive: true,
    isActive: "btn-primary",
    hasError: "btn-primary-outline"
  }
})
```

```css
button{
  padding: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.btn-primary{
  background: red;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.btn-primary-outline{
  background: transparent;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.11/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button v-on:click="settingsButtonIsActive = !settingsButtonIsActive" 
          :class="settingsButtonIsActive ? 'btn-primary' : 'btn-primary-outline'">
    <strong>{{msg}}</strong>: {{settingsButtonIsActive}}
  </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend rewriting the code a bit.

First of all, you can write the class name switch as a computed property:

```js
// ... beginning of your .js code
computed: {
    isButtonActive () {
      return this.settingsButtonIsActive ? 'btn-primary' : 'btn-outline-primary'
    }
}
// ... rest of your .js code
```

then you can merge both class attributes into one and bind it like this:

```html
<button v-on:click="settingsButtonIsActive = !settingsButtonIsActive" 
    :class="['btn', 'margin-top-half', 'center-block', 'col-xs-12', isButtonActiveClass">
  <strong>{{labels.lblButtonConfiguration}}</strong>
</button>
```

There is also another option, but because you change between two classes, I think a computed property is a much cleaner solution. However, you can achieve same result also with this code:

```html
<button v-on:click="settingsButtonIsActive = !settingsButtonIsActive" 
    :class="['btn', 'margin-top-half', 'center-block', 'col-xs-12', {'btn-primary': isButtonActiveClass}, {'btn-outline-primary': !isButtonActiveClass}">
  <strong>{{labels.lblButtonConfiguration}}</strong>
</button>
```

Note that when I want to change classes dynamically I'm passing an object into the array.

More can be found on https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by using the object syntax instead of the array syntax.

```
<button v-on:click="settingsButtonIsActive = !settingsButtonIsActive"
        class="btn margin-top-half center-block col-xs-12"
        :class="{'btn-primary' : settingsButtonIsActive === true, 'btn-primary-outline' : settingsButtonIsActive === false}">
    <strong>{{labels.lblButtonConfiguration}}</strong>
</button>
```

Comment: This is not a real "fix" (Longer code + less readable) - the (ternary) operator is the best idea for this case (See my answer).